# Is there any repository to hold scala wrappers for javascript libs?

Tags: scala, typescript, scala.js

Like [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped) for typescript, I wonder if there is any similar one for scalajs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This topic comes up periodically in the community. There have been one or two attempts to build something like that, but I haven't seen anything that's more than a start yet.

For the time being, the [Scala.js homepage itself](http://www.scala-js.org/) is being used for that purpose -- it's incomplete, but folks tend to put the more mature facades there. If you look down that page, it has a section on "Static types for JavaScript libraries". Pull Requests to add new ones are welcomed.